# Group property of toggle-button not working if I use ngIf with it

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui, togglebutton

#group property is not working when I am using ngIf in the toggle-group.

Code:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group *ngIf="query.noOfQuestions == 05" (change)="toggleChangeQuestion($event)" name="selectQuestions" #group1="matButtonToggleGroup">
    <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[0].answer==null" class="margin-right" value="0" checked>01</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[1].answer==null" class="margin-right" value="1">02</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[2].answer==null" class="margin-right" value="2">03</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[3].answer==null" class="margin-right" value="3">04</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[4].answer==null" value="4">05</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

```
<button (click)="test(group1)">Go</button>
```

In the test method in TS file, where I try to use group1.value, it returns the error **cannot set property 'value' of undefined**.

The code works fine if I remove the line ***ngIf="query.noOfQuestions == 05"**.

Kindly let me know if there is any workaround for this?

Complete HTML Code:

```
<div *ngIf="test?.length > 0">
    <mat-button-toggle-group *ngIf="query.noOfQuestions == 05" (change)="toggleChangeQuestion($event)" name="selectQuestions" #group1="matButtonToggleGroup">
        <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[0].answer==null" value="0" checked>01</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[1].answer==null" value="1">02</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[2].answer==null" value="2">03</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[3].answer==null" value="3">04</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[4].answer==null" value="4">05</mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
    <mat-button-toggle-group *ngIf="query.noOfQuestions == 10" (change)="toggleChangeQuestion($event)" name="selectQuestions" #group1="matButtonToggleGroup">
        <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[0].answer==null" value="0" checked>01</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[1].answer==null" value="1">02</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[2].answer==null" value="2">03</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[3].answer==null" value="3">04</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[4].answer==null" value="4">05</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[5].answer==null" value="5">06</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[6].answer==null" value="6">07</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[7].answer==null" value="7">08</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[8].answer==null" value="8">09</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="test[9].answer==null" value="9">10</mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
</div>

<button (click)="test(group1)">Test</button>
```

Comment: It seems pretty obvious that you are trying to grab an object that is no longer in the DOM due to your `*ngIf` statements, a possible solution would be to hide the buttons rather then remove them from the DOM however i can't help you any further then that with the code you have provided, maybe provide your ts and css that apply also

Comment: How do you suggest I should hide the buttons? Basically there is a check! If noOfQuestion = 05 it displays this group if its equals to 10, it renders the other group. Won't just hiding the buttons overlap the values too?

Comment: `ngClass` with the `opacity` set to 0 and `mouse-events` set to none maybe, again hard to help you with the small snippet you have provided and no example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added more HTML code above. I hope it helps enough for the problem to be understood. Thanks.

Comment: You are repeating alot of code in your HTML i would look into using `*ngFor` it will help you alot to minimise your code, as for your original issue i'm going to need to see your typescript/javascript and some css

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your original issue but an example of how to implement `*ngFor` that will help clean up your HTML code alot

```
<mat-button-toggle-group *ngIf="query.noOfQuestions == 10" (change)="toggleChangeQuestion($event)" name="selectQuestions" #group1="matButtonToggleGroup">
   <div *ngFor="let item of test; let i = index;">
    <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="!item.answer" value="{{i}}">{{i}}</mat-button-toggle>
   </div>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested. Now for more than 5 buttons it goes outside of the screen. [See here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WrXxs34Z7RHRXOdawniS25HLQ3Fk47yi/view?usp=sharing). No css is being applied till yet. how can I bring the 5+ buttons in the second line?

Comment: I NEED TO SEE YOUR CSS AND JS/TYPESCRIPT TO HELP YOU!

Comment: I figured it out with the help of another question. Thanks for suggesting the use of ngFor it made my code much smaller.